# Postgres permission for EXPLAIN

Tags: postgresql, permissions, security, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-performance

I would like to give user a permission to perform `EXPLAIN` but not to execute the `SELECT` itself. Is this doable in PostgreSQL?

Comment: There is no explicit privilege for that. You need to write a function with `security definer` that accepts a query and returns the execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function like the one below;

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.explain_this (
      l_query text,
      out explain text
    )
    RETURNS SETOF text AS
    $body$
    BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'explain (ANALYZE FALSE) ' || l_query;
    END;
    $body$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    SECURITY DEFINER
    COST 100 ROWS 1000;
```

And then arrange privileges;

```
  ALTER FUNCTION public.explain_this(l_query text, out explain text)
    OWNER TO some_user_with_select_only_privileges;

  GRANT EXECUTE
    ON FUNCTION public.explain_this(l_query text, out explain text) TO user_to_execute;
```

Comment: Be advised this is quite dangerous as open to sql injection.  A user could do the following:
    SELECT public.explain_this(' analyze delete from customers');

This would actually execute the query to delete rows from the customers table.